# How to tokenize a title with the dot inside, e.g. "Mr." and not "Mr" , and "It's" and not "It" and "s"?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I have written this code following NLTK documentation :

```
import nltk
#define pattern
pattern = r''' (?x)     # set flag to allow verbose regexps
        (?:[A-Z]\.)+    # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
        | \$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?    # currency and percentages, $12.40, 50%
        | \w+(?:-\w+)*  # words with internal hyphens
        | \.\.\.        # ellipsis
        |(?:Mr|Mrs|Dr|Ms)\.
        '''

sampletext = "Mr. Finch went to the bar but Dr. Liu wasn't there. It's o-k."
print(nltk.regexp_tokenize(sampletext, pattern))
```

Output :

```
['Mr', 'Finch', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'bar', 'but', 'Dr', 'Liu', 'wasn', 't', 'there', 'It', 's', 'o-k']
```

I actually want the sentence to be tokenized as : "Mr." , "Dr." "It's" etc.
I used this : `\w+(?:'\[a-z])*` for situations like can't and it's, but it is not working. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that this part of your regex:

```
        | \w+(?:-\w+)*  # words with internal hyphens
```

is matching all the normal words in your string because the `(?:-\w+)` is optional. This results in (for example) matching `Mr` before you get to the part of the regex that matches `Mr.`. You need to adjust your regex to remove the optionality of those parts and then just matching normal words at the end of the regex (when all other possible matches have failed). For example:

```py
import nltk

pattern = r''' (?x)             # set flag to allow verbose regexps
        (?:[A-Z]\.)+            # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
        | \$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?    # currency and percentages, $12.40, 50%
        | \w+(?:-\w+)+          # words with internal hyphens
        | \w+(?:'[a-z])         # words with apostrophes
        | \.\.\.                # ellipsis
        |(?:Mr|Mrs|Dr|Ms)\.     # honorifics
        | \w+                   # normal words
        '''

sampletext = "Mr. Finch went to the bar but Dr. Liu wasn't there. It's o-k."
print(nltk.regexp_tokenize(sampletext, pattern))
```

Output:

```py
['Mr.', 'Finch', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'bar', 'but', 'Dr.', 'Liu', "wasn't", 'there', "It's", 'o-k']
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I see my mistake now.